# How to align link to center?

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to figure out on how to align link to center. This is what I've got on my code.

```
    <div class="cont">
  <div class="form sign-in">
    <h2>Welcome back,</h2>
    <label>
      <span>Email</span>
      <input type="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Password</span>
      <input type="password" />
    </label>
    <a href="facebook.com"><span class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</span></a>
    <button type="button" class="submit">Sign In</button>
    <button type="button" class="fb-btn">Connect with <span>facebook</span></button>
  </div>
```

And this is my css code for the class "forgot-pass"

```
.forgot-pass {
   margin-top: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #cfcfcf;
}
    .cont {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  background: #fff;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1.2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 50px 30px 0;
 }
```

I've tried this code

```
<a href="facebook.com"><span class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</span></a>
```

the css class `.forgot-pass` had been applied but the `text-align:center` is the only one that have not been applied.

Is there something that I did wrong? Or another that I could get that in center?

Comment: You would need to set `text-align: center` on the parent of the `a`.

Answer (score 3):

Put the link inside the `p` tag. No span needed with your CSS:

```css
.forgot-pass {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

.forgot-pass a:link,
.forgot-pass a:visited {
  color: #cfcfcf;
}

.forgot-pass a:hover,
.forgot-pass a:active {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<p class="forgot-pass"><a href="facebook.com">Forgot password?</a></p>
```

Comment: Why would you wrap an anchor within a <p> tag? Isn't the purpose of <p> for paragraphs?

Comment: @ConsoleLog Because the original code from the question contained a `p` tag. And a paragraph can contain a link, i.e. an `a` tag. However, the `a` tag is inline, the `p`tag is a block, so with my code the link can be centered horizontally (since block elements have a default width of 100% unless they are floated, flex items or grid items.)

Comment: Fair enough. Thought your intention of wrapping it with paragraph was to just centralised the content :) Yeah, you could have more content inside paragraph but with this approach all text will be centralised as well.

Comment: @Johannes this is working for me, but how can i still apply the color silver?

Comment: @PeterFestejo I just added into the code what I had added as a plain note before: The link text color will overwrite its containers color, so you have to define it for the link iteslef (see my example in the edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
    .forgot-pass {
       margin-top: 15px;
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 12px;
       color: #cfcfcf;
      display: block;
    }

<a href="facebook.com"><span class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</span></a>
```

Add display block to the span

```css
.forgot-pass {
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="facebook.com"><span class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</span></a>
```

Comment: without a semi colon after display:block? I dont know why is that working on you but it's not working on mine.

Comment: Sorry I missed the semicolon.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to tell without seeing what's overarching your anchor element. I'd apply a border or background colour to the anchor within Chrome dev tools or something like that and do some basic debugging.

Comment: This will spread the link across the whole width of the container element instead of being only on the "Forgot password" text, which might not be desired. To avoid that, put the link into a block element and center it there (see the snippet in my answer)

Comment: @ConsoleLog I've edited my question, Is there any chances thats why im still having the same problem?

Comment: @Peter Festejo, I copied your code into this pen and not entirely sure since your form elements are sitting side by side?Do you want the forgot password link to be the only thing on that row as I'm trying to visualise your desired outcome? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejbwdK?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the problem is caused by both elements being inline elements. Inline elements will only take up as much horizontal space as required by the contents. As a result, setting `text-align: center;` will not produce a visible effect, as the text will only be centered in the element, which is the same size as the text itself. To center the text in the page, you can either set the position of the element manually (e.g. `position: absolute`), or make it a `block` element.

The following code will center the link on the page:

```
.forgot-pass {
   margin-top: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #cfcfcf;
   display: block;
}

<a href="facebook.com" class="forgot-pass">Forgot password?</a>
```

Comment: This will spread the link across the whole width of the container element instead of being only on the "Forgot password" text, which might not be desired. To avoid that, put the link into a block element and center it there (see the snippet in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

> You can do something like this

```
<body>
    <p class="forgot-pass">
        <a href="facebook.com">Forgot password?</a>
    </p>
</body>

.forgot-pass {
            margin-top: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #cfcfcf;
        }
```